# Error it results is DATE GOT NUMBER

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE sales ( ID INT NOT NULL, DATEn DATE, AMOUNT int);

Table created.

SQL> insert into sales values (1,2016-06-23,3600);
insert into sales values (1,2016-06-23,3600)
                                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
```

What are the correct date and time commands?

Comment: `2016-06-23` is `2016 minus 6 minus 23` - see the manual for the correct way of specifying a date literal: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert your column value to date, try this:

```
insert into sales values (1,to_date('2016-06-23','yyyy-mm-dd'),3600);
```