# Fetching data from Oracle to Sql in variables in SSIS

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis

I have a table in Oracle something like this

user_id     |  Name     |     Process_Date
1           |   ABC     |     11/14/2017 5:14:18 PM

I want to use the parameter in ssis for oracle source. Now I created 1 string variable Check and passed the expression as

```
SUBSTRING( (DT_STR,50, 1256)DATEADD("DAY",-1,GETDATE()) , 1, 10)
```

It gives me 2017-11-14 in the value

When In Ole DB Source I write query as

```
select * from Test where trunc(process_date) = ?. It gives me an error.
```

Then I tried to use variable and load the query in variable something like

```
" select * from Test
where trunc(process_date) ="+ @[User::Check]
```

I checked the variable properties ' EvaluateasExpression' it's True.

But still it gives me an error " Inconsistent datatypes: Expected Date got Number

What is missing here can anyone tell me???

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a problem with converting date string to date: [Error it results is DATE GOT NUMBER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219384/error-it-results-is-date-got-number)

So the expression needs to be like this:

```
    "select * from Test
    where trunc(process_date) = to_date('"+ @[User::Check] + "','yyyy-mm-dd')"
```

Comment: When I am adding the above query in Ole DB source it is not giving me any error like previously. But when I click on preview there is no data. i checked the date and it is fine.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Oracle, maybe the datatypes don't match. What datatype is the Process_Date column? Does it return something if you hardcode a date to the query and make sure the database contains the date you try to search for?

Comment: Process_date is Date data type.

Comment: Did you make sure, there's data for that date? It seems to be fine, I tested it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/520e2/1